# IdentityServer/OWIN: Client not being redirected to Login page after Logout

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3, owin-middleware

I have a new IdP that implements IdentityServer4 (.NET Core).  I am using it to provide SSO/Cookie authentication/authorization to an MVC5 client app.  Since the client app is not .NET Core, I use the IdentityServer3 and Microsoft.Owin nugets in order to integrate.  There aren't tons of examples of mixing .NET Core and .NET together like this, but there are a few and I've done my best to make it work.  Here is the configuration source code for each:

IdentityServer4 (.NET Core, based largely on this [example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/Combined_AspNetIdentity_and_EntityFrameworkStorage)):

```
new Client()
{
    ClientId = "myClientId",
    ClientName = "My Client",
    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
    Enabled = true,
    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },
    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
    }
}
```

My Client (MVC5):

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
});
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
    ClientId = "myClientId",
    RedirectUri = "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc",
    ResponseType = "code id_token",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
    Scope = "openid",
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
    {
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = n => {
            n.OwinContext.Response.Cookies.Append("stored_id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        },
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = n => {
            if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
            {
                var idTokenHint = n.Request.Cookies["stored_id_token"];
                if (idTokenHint != null)
                {
                    n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint;
                    var signOutMessageId = n.OwinContext.Environment.GetSignOutMessageId();  // returns NULL!
                    //var signOutMessageId = n.OwinContext.Request.Query.Get("id");  // same thing as line above
                    if (signOutMessageId != null)
                    {
                        n.ProtocolMessage.State = signOutMessageId;
                    }
                }
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Logout mostly works ok.  The issue I have is with redirecting back to the login page so that the enduser can login again to the client they just logged out of via the link highlighted here:
[image: The link highlighted here]
The RedirectUri is configured correctly on both sides of configuration (IdP and Client), and the hyperlink's href value is set in the View (pictured), but that URL also needs a query param called "state" attached to it so that it knows which application to log back into (eg. http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc?state=123456789  Clicking this link without the "state" param gives you a 404.).  The issue I'm having is that I'm unable to get/set this "state" value in "My Client".

From everything I've read, you get it by calling `n.OwinContext.Environment.GetSignOutMessageId()` which is actually just calling `n.OwinContext.Request.Query.Get("id")` under the covers, but it always returns null. Any idea why this returns null??
Thank you!

Comment: Much of what I'm describing is documented here:  https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/federated-post-logout-redirect.html

Comment: Use `PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:5002` for MVC client in client configurations as well as use the same in MVC5 client startup.cs OpenId Connect authentication configurations.

Comment: Thanks.  Tried that, it had no effect.